# Conky network issue on 18.04

Tags: conky

So I have heard a lot about conky and wanted to give it a try. I added [TeeJee ppa](http://www.teejeetech.in/p/conky-manager.html), installed it and downloaded the official theme pack. The problem is, conky is unable to detect network interface. After spending some time on google, I realized that I have to replace `eth0` with `enp1s0` to get conky work with network connection. So here is my current `systemstat` widget that comes with **TransparentTilesV3** theme:

```
TEXT
${voffset -2}${font Open Sans Light:bold:size=9}HARD DRIVEs$font${voffset 10}
HOME ${alignr}${color5}${fs_bar 12,200 /home}
${voffset -18}${offset 5}${color}${alignr 5}$color${fs_free /home}$color$font
SYSTEM ${alignr}${color5}${fs_bar 12,200 /}
${voffset -18}${offset 5}${color}${alignr 5}$color${fs_free /} free$color$font
${voffset -8}
${font Open Sans Light:bold:size=9}NETWORK$font${voffset -14}
${if_existing /proc/net/route wlan0}
${color}Up:${color} ${color2}${upspeed wlan0}${color}${alignr}${color}Sent:${color} ${color2}${totalup wlan0}${color}
${color}Down:${color} ${color2}${downspeed wlan0}${color}${alignr}${color}Received:${color} ${color2}${totaldown wlan0}${color}
${else}${if_existing /proc/net/route wlan1}
${color}Up:${color} ${color2}${upspeed wlan1}${color}${alignr}${color}Sent:${color} ${color2}${totalup wlan1}${color}
${color}Down:${color} ${color2}${downspeed wlan1}${color}${alignr}${color}Received:${color} ${color2}${totaldown wlan1}${color}
${else}${if_existing /proc/net/route enp1s0}
${color}Up:${color} ${color2}${upspeed enp1s0}${color}${alignr}${color}Sent:${color} ${color2}${totalup enp1s0}${color}
${color}Down:${color} ${color2}${downspeed enp1s0}${color}${alignr}${color}Received:${color} ${color2}${totaldown enp1s0}${color}
${else}${if_existing /proc/net/route eth1}
${color}Up:${color} ${color2}${upspeed eth1}${color}${alignr}${color}Sent:${color} ${color2}${totalup eth1}${color}
${color}Down:${color} ${color2}${downspeed eth1}${color}${alignr}${color}Received:${color} ${color2}${totaldown eth1}${color}
${else}${if_existing /proc/net/route ppp0}
${color}Up:${color} ${color2}${upspeed ppp0}${color}${alignr}${color}Sent:${color} ${color2}${totalup ppp0}${color}
${color}Down:${color} ${color2}${downspeed ppp0}${color}${alignr}${color}Received:${color} ${color2}${totaldown ppp0}${color}
${else}${if_existing /proc/net/route ppp1}
${color}Up:${color} ${color2}${upspeed ppp1}${color}${alignr}${color}Sent:${color} ${color2}${totalup ppp1}${color}
${color}Down:${color} ${color2}${downspeed ppp1}${color}${alignr}${color}Received:${color} ${color2}${totaldown ppp1}${color}
${else}${if_existing /proc/net/route usb0}
${color}Up:${color} ${color2}${upspeed usb0}${color}${alignr}${color}Sent:${color} ${color2}${totalup usb0}${color}
${color}Down:${color} ${color2}${downspeed usb0}${color}${alignr}${color}Received:${color} ${color2}${totaldown usb0}${color}
${else}${if_existing /proc/net/route usb1}
${color}Up:${color} ${color2}${upspeed usb1}${color}${alignr}${color}Sent:${color} ${color2}${totalup usb1}${color}
${color}Down:${color} ${color2}${downspeed usb1}${color}${alignr}${color}Received:${color} ${color2}${totaldown usb1}${color}
${else}
Network disconnected
${color5}Connect to a network to see statistics${color}
${voffset 74}
${endif}${endif}${endif}${endif}${endif}${endif}${endif}${endif}${voffset -61}
```

I just searched for text: eth0 and replaced it with enp1s0, but not all widget comes with the text `eth0`, for instance, the news widget:

```
# conky package by qaisar nawaz
# Conky settings #
background no
update_interval 900
double_buffer yes
no_buffers yes

# Window specifications #
own_window yes
own_window_type normal
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
own_window_title
own_window_colour bebebe
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_argb_value 205

minimum_size 549 85
maximum_width 549

# Alignment #
alignment tr
gap_x 55
gap_y 341

border_inner_margin 10
border_outer_margin 0

# Graphics settings #
draw_shades no
draw_outline no
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no

# Text settings #
use_xft yes
xftalpha 0
xftfont Open Sans Light:size=10

override_utf8_locale yes

imlib_cache_size 0

# Color scheme #
default_color 333333

color1 0099CC
color2 9933CC
color3 669900
color4 FF8800
color5 CC0000
color6 AAAAAA
color7 DDDDDD

TEXT
${voffset -4}${color1}${font Open Sans Light:size=12}Top Stories - Google News$color$font
${voffset 1}${exec python ./news.py}
${voffset -28}
```

I even tried to wrap the TEXT portion inside a for loop like this:

```
TEXT
${if_existing /proc/net/route enp1s0}
${voffset -4}${color1}${font Open Sans Light:size=12}Top Stories - Google News$color$font
${voffset 1}${exec python ./news.py}
${voffset -28}
${endif}
```

But still no luck... How can I tell conky to use enp1s0 globally, instead of eth0?

Comment: Since you got `conky` from " TeeJee ppa", questions should go there.

Comment: @waltinator I did not install `conky` from there, I just installed Conky Manager and the themes from there. Just in case you don't know what it is: It's a graphical front end that helps beginners (like myself) get used to conky.